# Bootstrap fix column to the left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Demo: [full page](http://codepen.io/MWalid/full/AFklh) or [with editor.](http://codepen.io/MWalid/pen/AFklh)

Currently `.col-sm-6 .tasks-panel` placed at the right side when the previous `.col-sm-6` isn't too long, goes to the left when the previous is long enough (click `Add Visit` on the demo to make the previous longer).

I want to fix it always to the left side.

I have tried `.pull-left` unfortunately it didn't work.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you haven't closed your `<div class="row">`, which should be closed at the end of everything.

Secondly, to keep the two right blocks on the right at all times, you need to place them both in the same `<div class="col-md-6">`

Here is the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RkrmR/)**

**Update**

Sorry, I got it wrong, I thought you want them both on the right side.
Here is what you have to do to keep them on the left side: **[demo-2](http://jsfiddle.net/RkrmR/1/)**

Comment: Thanks so much, but your answer is partially correct because it doesn't maintain the hierarchy of panels in `xs` size, original ordering was: 1-calendar, 2-outlets-panel, 3-tasks-panel.In your solution the hierarchy become: 1-calendar, 2-tasks-panel, 3-outlets-panel.